# Loop Through All Sheets and Combine Into One Email with Conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, email

so I have a dynamic number of sheets and I would like to loop through all of it then combine the data in all of the sheets into one email.
The condition is, if cell A1 of the sheets is blank, it will copy everything in that sheet. But if cell A1 of the sheets is not blank, it will only copy cell B2, put two blank lines below and then copy the data in cell E10 of my Email Sheet.

Here's my code. This only does the last sheet.

```
            Sub EmailReport()
        
        Application.ReferenceStyle = xlA1
        
        Dim rawSh As Worksheet
        Dim ainfoSh As Worksheet
        Dim emSh As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim LastRow1 As Long
        Dim LastRow2 As Long
        
        Dim SigString As String
        Dim Signature As String
        Dim SignatureRTA As String
        
        Set rawSh = Worksheets("Raw Data")
        Set ainfoSh = Worksheets("Info")
        Set emSh = Worksheets("Email")
          
                
                      ' By Ron de Bruin.
                    
                    Dim OutApp As Object
                    Dim OutMail As Object
                    
                    With Application
                        .EnableEvents = False
                        .ScreenUpdating = False
                    End With
        
                    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
                    With OutMail
                        .BodyFormat = 2
                        .To = emSh.Range("C6").Value
                        .CC = emSh.Range("C7").Value
                        .BCC = ""
                        .Subject = emSh.Range("C5").Value
                        
                       'loop through all worksheets
                        For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets()
                            Set rng = Nothing
                            SheetName = wks.Name
                            
                            On Error Resume Next
                            'check if the name of the sheet is included in the funds list
                            Set rng = ainfoSh.Range("I:I").Find(SheetName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                            On Error GoTo 0
                            
                            If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo NextWorksheet   'NOT included in list
                            
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Surpress warning message
                            'my code here
                    
                            lastRow = wks.Range("B:C").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow1 = wks.Range("E:Q").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                            LastRow2 = wks.Range("S:AA").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                
                            Set rng = Nothing
                            ' Only send the visible cells in the selection.
                            x = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                         
                            Set rng = wks.Range("B2:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            Set rng1 = wks.Range("E4:Q" & LastRow1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            Set rng2 = wks.Range("S4:AA" & LastRow2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                            Set rng3 = wks.Range("B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                
                            If rng Is Nothing Then
                                MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
                                       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                           
        '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE IS
                            If wks.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                        
                                .HTMLBody = "<table align = left>" & emSh.Range("C8") & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML1(rng1) & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML1(rng2) 
                        
                            Else
                            
                                .HTMLBody = "<table align = left>" & emSh.Range("C8") & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML3(rng3) & "<Br>" & "<Br>" & emSh.Range("E10") 
                                
                            End If
        '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                            
          NextWorksheet:
                        Next wks
                
                        Set ainfoSh = Nothing
                        
                        .Importance = 2
                       ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
                        ' display the e-mail message.
                        .Display
                    End With
                    On Error GoTo 0
        
                    With Application
                        .EnableEvents = True
                        .ScreenUpdating = True
                    End With
        
                    Set OutMail = Nothing
                    Set OutApp = Nothing
        
                   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        
            Set rng = Nothing
            
        End Sub
```

The code enclosed in '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> is the part I am having troubles with. Please help. I appreciate all the help I will get. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after each iteration, you are replacing the value of `.HTMLBody`. You are not keeping the previous value(s).

Try:

```
 If wks.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                        
   .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<table align = left>" & emSh.Range("C8") & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML(rng) & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML1(rng1) & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML1(rng2) 
                        
Else
                            
   .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<table align = left>" & emSh.Range("C8") & "<Br>" & RangetoHTML3(rng3) & "<Br>" & "<Br>" & emSh.Range("E10") 
                                
End If
```

Comment: Perfect! :)
Thank you so much! :)